# Error while exporting project in jar ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jfreechart

Im working on app that will show charts. I did already working classes using JFreeChart. I want to use them in other project. Im exporting it into "runnable jar with package required libraries into jar" option. When I add jar into new project I can see in referenced libraries my classes which I made and JFree libraries but when Im trying to use it, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel
```

Something like that works fine in project where I wrote classes:

```
Statistics stat=new Statistics(new Cards(path)); //showing chart
```

And same thing in new project with imported jar causes errors.

Comment: How did you created your JAR file?

Comment: Im using eclipse. Project->Export>Java>Runnable Jar

Comment: Can you post the last window when you select "Runnable JAR"? The link is OK, I can edit it so the image can be seen

Comment: See also [*JFreeChart Java JAR not running on a different machine*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22071389/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Always double check your work and make sure you don't have an extra or misplaced  } or ;.  They can very easily ruin an otherwise perfect string of code.

Comment: The problem is with exporting project. I got one called f.e "Stats". Im creating class with main function and calling there :                               Statistics stat=new Statistics(new Cards(path)); works perfectly. Then I want to use exported project "Stats" in other project. Adding jar and same line of code into main and I get error. Its not problem with code..

Comment: I would suggest initializing the jar before the main, and possibly making a new method for it if that doesn't help.